# XML and Delphi problem

Tags: xml, delphi

I am trying to implement a protocol which I will use for my application to communicate with a server. The problem is that the server is using XML so I tried to send a string to the server containing xml but I get only errors.

When I send this :

```
mymsg: String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
'<m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints"'+
'xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg"'+
'xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;&gt;'+
'&lt;content xsi:type=&quot;HeartBeatcmd&quot;&gt;'+
'&lt;/content&gt;'+
'&lt;csq&gt;100212&lt;/csq&gt;'+
'&lt;/m:outgoingEngineMessage&gt;';
```

I receive an error saying:

> Element type "m:outgoingEngineMessage" must be followed by either
>   attribute specifications, "&gt ;" or "/&gt ;"

When I send this:

```
mymsg : String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
    '&lt;m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c=&quot;http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints"'+
    'xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg"'+
    'xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;&gt;'+
    '&lt;content xsi:type=&quot;HeartBeatcmd&quot;&gt;'+
    '&lt;/content&gt;'+
    '&lt;csq&gt;100212&lt;/csq&gt;'+
    '&lt;/m:outgoingEngineMessage&gt;'
```

I get: Element not allowed in prolog...

Can some one enlighten me what I am doing wrong? I have never worked with xml files before. Is there a function to convert xml to utf8 correctly? please explain.

Comment: if you search the web for example documents with "xmlns:xsi" it is easy to see they use a quote like `xmlns:xsi="...` and not `xmlns:xsi=&quot...`, and other obvious differences like a closing `</whatever>` tag for the root element. In your example, the terminating `</m:outgoingEngineMessage>` is missing.

Comment: Ouch! Don't "hand-generate" the XML - use a library to do this. It will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to put a space at the end of each line where the line break is between attributes. You are in effect jamming them all together:

```
<m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints"'+
'xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg"'+
'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
```

will produce:

```
<m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints"xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

To fix this, you need to do something like the following (based on @The_Fox's code):

```
mymsg: String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
'<m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints" '+
//                                                          see the space here --^
'xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg" '+
//                                   and here --^
'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
'<content xsi:type="HeartBeatcmd">'+
'</content>'+
'<csq>100212</csq>'+
'</m:outgoingEngineMessage>';
```

Comment: Yes, there are a few of us around :)

Answer (score 6):

The safest way to generate 'well-formed' XML is using an XML library like [NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html), [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) (both open source) or the MSXML library (Delphi provides a wrapper for it).

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping < and > where you shouldn't. Only escape those entities when they are not part of the xml.

Like this:

```
<content foo="bar">
2 + 2 &gt; 3
</content>
```

And not like this:

```
&lt;content foo=&quot;bar%quot;&gt;
2 + 2 &gt; 3
&lt;/content&gt;
```

So your xml would look like this:

```
mymsg: String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
'<m:outgoingEngineMessage xmlns:c="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/constraints" '+
'xmlns:m="http://www.bvb.ro/xml/ns/arena/gw/msg" '+
'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
'<content xsi:type="HeartBeatcmd">'+
'</content>'+
'<csq>100212</csq>'+
'</m:outgoingEngineMessage>';
```

Comment: I still get this error message : Element type "m:outgoingEngineMessage" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "&gt;" or "/&gt;".

Comment: XML- and XHTML-documents must have white wpaces between the Attributes, the code however builds `.../constraints"xmlns:m="http...`, better show the correct XML code (instead of the Delphi constant declaration)

Comment: Put a space before you close the string for each line, for instance `...gw/constants" ' +`